# Spring MVC - Servlet dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a working AngularJS + Spring MVC application called A. This web application has been cloned (ctrl+c & ctrl+v upon the project folder) into another called B.

Trying to run both they (naturally) have the same behavior.

My goal is to simplify A but I got stuck at the first step where I wish to do is to make a bit of refactoring to folders containing `.html` files.

A tree folders is the following:

```
src/main/webapp
           |--- WEB-INF/
           |--- META-INF/
           |--- static/
                   |--- js/
                   |--- css/
                   |--- index.html
                   |--- sth.html
```

The transformation on B is:

```
src/main/webapp
           |--- META-INF/
           |--- js/
           |--- css/
           |--- index.html
           |--- sth.html
```

Briefly, I moved all resources inside the `static` folder one level up.

The next step is to adapt the A `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` starting from the old one (yeah, I'll do a better organized code once solved... ARG!!!):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.name")
public class Configurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/static/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //resources locations

        // html
        registry.addResourceHandler("static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("static/modals/**").addResourceLocations("/static/modals/");

        // css
        registry.addResourceHandler("css/**").addResourceLocations("/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("css/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/static/css/bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/fullcalendar/dist/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/fullcalendar/dist/");

        // scripts
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/jquery/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/jquery/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/bootstrap/umd/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/bootstrap/umd/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/angular/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/angular/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/angular/animate/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/angular/animate/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/angular/ui-router/release/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/angular/ui-router/release/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/angular-ui-calendar/src/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/angular-ui-calendar/src/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/fullcalendar/dist/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/fullcalendar/dist/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/moment/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/moment/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/angular-ui-grid/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/angular-ui-grid/");

        // custom
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/service/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/service/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/controller/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/controller/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/controller/modals/**").addResourceLocations("/static/js/controller/modals/");
    }

}
```

to a new one for B:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.name")
public class Configurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //resources locations

        // html
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");

        // css
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/css/bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/fullcalendar/dist/**").addResourceLocations("/js/fullcalendar/dist/");

        // scripts
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/jquery/**").addResourceLocations("/js/jquery/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/js/bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/bootstrap/umd/**").addResourceLocations("/js/bootstrap/umd/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/angular/**").addResourceLocations("/js/angular/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/angular/animate/**").addResourceLocations("/js/angular/animate/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/angular/ui-router/release/**").addResourceLocations("/js/angular/ui-router/release/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/angular-ui-calendar/src/**").addResourceLocations("/js/angular-ui-calendar/src/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/fullcalendar/dist/**").addResourceLocations("/js/fullcalendar/dist/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/moment/**").addResourceLocations("/js/moment/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/angular-ui-grid/**").addResourceLocations("/js/angular-ui-grid/");

        // custom
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/service/**").addResourceLocations("/js/service/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/controller/**").addResourceLocations("/js/controller/");
    }

}
```

as it's shown, I removed `static/` prefix on each path.

Once run, recursively the browser's console gives me `Error 500` requesting `sth` despite succeeding to show me the `index.html`

```
GET http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/sth 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

while Tomcat is logging this exception all time long:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:221)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:221)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:221)
// lots of times...

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)

//To the infinity and beyond! (cit.)... unless tomcat shutdown
```

This is the index controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndexPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

}
```

The controller to manage the `sth` page

```
@Controller
public class TemplateController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sth")
    public ModelAndView getGrid() {
        return new ModelAndView("sth");
    }

}
```

`angular.ui` router within `app.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('MyWebApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.calendar',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.grid'
]);

//globals
app.value('baseUrl', '/MyWebApp');

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sth');

    $stateProvider.state('sth', {
        url: '/sth',
        templateUrl: 'sth',
        controller: 'sthCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'sth'
    });

});
```

and, finally, the `sthCtrl` file

```
app.controller('sthCtrl', function ($http, baseUrl) {
    var scope = this;
    scope.users = [];
    scope.structures = [];

    $http.get(baseUrl + '/users').then(function (userResp) {
        scope.users = userResp.data;
    });

    $http.get(baseUrl + '/structures').then(function (structureResp) {
        scope.structures = structureResp.data;
    });

});
```

I MUST have missed something that I can't see... however, I have some suspects:

1) Within the `Configurations` class: May I have forgot something; 
2) It's a front-end structural problem: Creating `static` folder and moving all the previous crowd inside (changed also paths on `Configurations` class) "automagically" `Error 500` disappears and I can see my HTML! (OMG) so I guess if AngularJS need `static` folder and if I don't want that I must tell it in someway... but the exception on Tomcat still be (crap...)

Having few experience with both AngularJS and Spring MVC I can't work out what I'm missing.

Comment: Try changing the name of sth.html to something else and don't forget to change it also in the controller return new ModelAndView("sth");

Comment: Actually `sth` is a generic placeholder I used in this thread but in reality its name is `grid` because that page shows a table.

Comment: I asked you this because your @RequestMapping(value = "/sth")
    public ModelAndView getGrid() {
        return new ModelAndView("sth");
    }    I think probably this is causing an infinity bucle.

Comment: Yeah you're right my mistake ;) But it's not clear why I get that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string that will be resolved into a `View` by `ViewResolver`, try something like this to avoid you an infinity loop :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/sth")
  public String getGrid() {
    return "someThing";
}
```

Comment: Actually I do not have a web.xml. I'm using Spring with annotations on both A and B applications.